# Multiple visual WebPart

Tags: web-part, visual-studio

i have created a sharepoint 2010 project, under this project i want to add multiple visual

webparts but i want to deploy just one not all.

it'is possible ? and how

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many as you like in the solution but only include the ones you want deployed by selecting them in the Feature designer.

Comment: Thx for answer ;)